# Hierarchy is returning heights and lengths that are NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on my first treemap and i am unable to get the rect objects to render.  The console is telling me that the length and width of each rect is NaN.  Here's my code for the map:

```
  //tree map
const drawTreeMap = (data) => {
  const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data)
    .sum((d) => d.value)
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

  const treeMap = d3.treemap().size(height, width);

  const root = treeMap(hierarchy)

console.log(root.leaves())

  const map = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (item) => {
      "translate(" + item["x0"] + ", " + item["y0"] + ")";
    });

  map
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "tile")
    .attr("fill", (item) => {
      let category = item.data.category;
      let color = categories.filter((c, i) => {
        if (category == c) {
          return colors[i];
        }
      });
      return color;
    })
    .attr("data-name", (item) => item.data.name)
    .attr("data-category", (item) => item.data.category)
    .attr("data-value", (item) => item.data.value)
    .attr("width", (item) => item["x1"] - item["x0"])
    .attr("height", (item) => item["y1"] - item["y0"])
  
}
drawTreeMap(data);
```

});

I know that the json file is being read properly and I can see when I console log the root.leaves() that x1 and y1 values are NaN.  I've consulted 4-5 different tutorials on treemaps and I am unable to find anything that works.  I am using d3 v6.6 and the json file is here:

[json file](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/movie-data.json)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your `value`s might need to be coerced to numbers since they're stored as strings. The plus sign is a shorthand way of doing this: try `.sum((d) => +d.value)`

Comment: I actually tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have found the solution.  I replaced  `const treeMap = d3.treemap().size(height, width);

  const root = treeMap(hierarchy)`  with  `d3.treemap().size([width, height])(hierarchy);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter well, the code in your question and in your answer are the same, chaining it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752693/5768908) is not the solution: both your original code and the code in your answer produce **exactly the same** array. You can see it here (using v5, but that doesn't matter):

```js
const data = {
  "name": "Movies",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Action",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Avatar ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "760505847"
    }, {
      "name": "Jurassic World ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "652177271"
    }, {
      "name": "The Avengers ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "623279547"
    }, {
      "name": "The Dark Knight ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "533316061"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "474544677"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "460935665"
    }, {
      "name": "Avengers: Age of Ultron ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "458991599"
    }, {
      "name": "The Dark Knight Rises ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "448130642"
    }, {
      "name": "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "423032628"
    }, {
      "name": "Iron Man 3",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "408992272"
    }, {
      "name": "Captain America: Civil War ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "407197282"
    }, {
      "name": "Spider-Man ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "403706375"
    }, {
      "name": "Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "402076689"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "380262555"
    }, {
      "name": "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "377019252"
    }, {
      "name": "Spider-Man 2",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "373377893"
    }, {
      "name": "Deadpool ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "363024263"
    }, {
      "name": "Transformers: Dark of the Moon ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "352358779"
    }, {
      "name": "American Sniper ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "350123553"
    }, {
      "name": "Furious 7",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "350034110"
    }, {
      "name": "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "340478898"
    }, {
      "name": "Spider-Man 3",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "336530303"
    }, {
      "name": "Minions ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "336029560"
    }, {
      "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "333130696"
    }, {
      "name": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "330249062"
    }, {
      "name": "Transformers ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "318759914"
    }, {
      "name": "Iron Man ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "318298180"
    }, {
      "name": "Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "317011114"
    }, {
      "name": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "313837577"
    }, {
      "name": "Iron Man 2",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "312057433"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "310675583"
    }, {
      "name": "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "309404152"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "309125409"
    }, {
      "name": "Independence Day ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "306124059"
    }, {
      "name": "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "305388685"
    }, {
      "name": "Skyfall ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "304360277"
    }, {
      "name": "Inception ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "292568851"
    }, {
      "name": "Man of Steel ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "291021565"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "290158751"
    }, {
      "name": "The Matrix Reloaded ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "281492479"
    }, {
      "name": "The Amazing Spider-Man ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "262030663"
    }, {
      "name": "The Incredibles ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "261437578"
    }, {
      "name": "Captain America: The Winter Soldier ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "259746958"
    }, {
      "name": "The Lego Movie ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "257756197"
    }, {
      "name": "Star Trek ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "257704099"
    }, {
      "name": "Batman ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "251188924"
    }, {
      "name": "Night at the Museum ",
      "category": "Action",
      "value": "250863268"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Drama",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Titanic ",
      "category": "Drama",
      "value": "658672302"
    }, {
      "name": "The Sixth Sense ",
      "category": "Drama",
      "value": "293501675"
    }, {
      "name": "I Am Legend ",
      "category": "Drama",
      "value": "256386216"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Adventure",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Shrek 2",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "436471036"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "424645577"
    }, {
      "name": "The Lion King ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "422783777"
    }, {
      "name": "Toy Story 3",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "414984497"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hunger Games ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "407999255"
    }, {
      "name": "Frozen ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "400736600"
    }, {
      "name": "Finding Nemo ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "380838870"
    }, {
      "name": "The Jungle Book ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "362645141"
    }, {
      "name": "Jurassic Park ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "356784000"
    }, {
      "name": "Inside Out ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "356454367"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "337103873"
    }, {
      "name": "Alice in Wonderland ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "334185206"
    }, {
      "name": "Shrek the Third ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "320706665"
    }, {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "317557891"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "303001229"
    }, {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "301956980"
    }, {
      "name": "The Twilight Saga: Eclipse ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "300523113"
    }, {
      "name": "The Twilight Saga: New Moon ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "296623634"
    }, {
      "name": "Up ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "292979556"
    }, {
      "name": "The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "292298923"
    }, {
      "name": "The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "292298923"
    }, {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "292000866"
    }, {
      "name": "The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "291709845"
    }, {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "289994397"
    }, {
      "name": "Monsters, Inc. ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "289907418"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "281666058"
    }, {
      "name": "Gravity ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "274084951"
    }, {
      "name": "Monsters University ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "268488329"
    }, {
      "name": "Shrek ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "267652016"
    }, {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "261970615"
    }, {
      "name": "Jaws ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "260000000"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "258355354"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "255108370"
    }, {
      "name": "Men in Black ",
      "category": "Adventure",
      "value": "250147615"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Family",
    "children": [{
      "name": "E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial ",
      "category": "Family",
      "value": "434949459"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Animation",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Despicable Me 2",
      "category": "Animation",
      "value": "368049635"
    }, {
      "name": "The Secret Life of Pets ",
      "category": "Animation",
      "value": "323505540"
    }, {
      "name": "Despicable Me ",
      "category": "Animation",
      "value": "251501645"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Comedy",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Forrest Gump ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "329691196"
    }, {
      "name": "Home Alone ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "285761243"
    }, {
      "name": "Meet the Fockers ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "279167575"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hangover ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "277313371"
    }, {
      "name": "How the Grinch Stole Christmas ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "260031035"
    }, {
      "name": "The Hangover Part II ",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "value": "254455986"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Biography",
    "children": [{
      "name": "The Blind Side ",
      "category": "Biography",
      "value": "255950375"
    }]
  }]
};

const height = 100, width = 100;

const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data)
  .sum((d) => d.value)
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

const treeMap = d3.treemap().size([height, width]);

const root = treeMap(hierarchy)

console.log(root.leaves())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, there is no `NaN`.

The real issue is that in your original code you're not passing `width` and `height` to the `size()` method as an array...

```
const treeMap = d3.treemap().size(height, width);
//no array here ------------------^------------^
```

...which you are in your answer (by the way, in the reversed order):

```
d3.treemap().size([width, height])(hierarchy);
//array here -----^-------------^
```

Comment: Aha!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just got it working by combining the lines:

```
  const treeMap = d3.treemap().size(height, width);

  const root = treeMap(hierarchy)
```

with one line:

```
  d3.treemap().size([width, height])(hierarchy);
```

full replacement:

```
    //tree map
const drawTreeMap = () => {
  
  const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data, (node) => node.children)
    .sum((node) => node.value)
    .sort((node1, node2) => node2.value - node1.value);

  d3.treemap().size([width, height])(hierarchy);
  
  const tiles = hierarchy.leaves();

  const block = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(tiles)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (item) => "translate(" + item.x0 + ", " + item.y0 + ")");

  block
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "tile")
    .attr("fill", (item) => {
      let category = item.data.category;
      console.log(item)
      let color = categories.filter((c, i) => {
        if (category == c) {
          return colors[i];
        }
      });
      return color[0];
    })
    .attr("data-name", (item) => item.data.name)
    .attr("data-category", (item) => item.data.category)
    .attr("data-value", (item) => item.data.value)
    .attr("width", (item) => item["x1"] - item["x0"])
    .attr("height", (item) => item["y1"] - item["y0"])
  
}
drawTreeMap();
```

});